# How to stream a queue across multiple subscriber?

Tags: concurrency, clojure

What I am trying to accomplish on higher level:

I have a function that does I/O and generate messages. I have multiple subscriber clients that can subscribe or leave at any time. When a new client subscribes, it should get x number of previous output before streaming new messages (much like unix "tail -f").

My idea was to send-off the messages to an agent, which is a ring buffer. New clients will read the agent and then add-watch to the agent. Problem is, how can I ensure no new message arrive between reading and add-watch?

Next idea was to create 2 refs, one for a list of clients, one for the ring buffer. I can then add clients or post message in transactions. Problem is, when I add clients, I have to read the ring buffer and send it to the client (I/O). This is side effect in transaction that may be retried.

Last idea is to use locks, but that can't be the only way?

Comment: What you are describing looks alot like what's Kafka is doing. Did you have look at it?

Comment: or RabbitMQ.  http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. After reading Kafka, I realized that by adding a unique message ID, I don't need to worry about sending duplicate message. This simplifies many things, since the message doesn't have to be strictly ordered.